# dplyr workflow for replacing and modifying variables

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I change variables in a data frame when using dplyr in a pipe?

For example, I want to read in a file and replace `NA` values with zero and also sort the date column?

```
# read file
df <- readr("myfile.txt") %>% janitor::clean_names()

# sort by data
df$date <- lubridate::ymd(df$date)
df <- dplyr::arrange(df, date)

# change NA to zero
df$cost[is.na(df$cost)] <- 0
```

How can I move these to the pipe workflow above when reading in the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do the following :

```
df <- readr("myfile.txt") %>%
 janitor::clean_names() %>%
 mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date),
        cost = ifelse(is.na(cost), 0, cost)) %>%
 arrange(date)
```